# Xamarin Forms navigation issue

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm working on a Xamarin Forms app, and I've ran into an issue.

The navigation system seems to be off a bit. I'm using a root NavigationPage to host my pages, and it works fine all time, except...

I have a sub-page with a list of items. When tapped, each item should display information about itself, on a separate page (let it be modal or not).

However, it only works the first time. The second time I try to check an entry, it seemingly loads it twice (font is thicker and a bit ghosty), and when I press back, one layer stays behind while the other moves with the close animation (that's why I think it was loaded twice).

The code is the following:

```cs
public partial class NotesPage : ContentPage {
protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        NotesList.ItemsSource = VM.Notes; // VM is my ViewModel, NotesList is a ListView defined in XAML
        NotesList.ItemSelected += async (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (e.SelectedItem == null) return;
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new NoteDetails((Note)e.Item));
            ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null;
        };
    }
}
```

```xml
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                       x:Class="Views.Notes.NoteDetails">
  <StackLayout>
    <Label Text="{Binding Title}" />
    <Label Text="{Binding Date}" />
    <Label Text="{Binding Author}" />
    <Label Text="{Binding Content}" />
  </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

NoteDetails' class only sets the BindingContext to the Note object passed.
The Note class has four properties: a String Title, a String Date (its code-back field is a DateTime object, conversion happens in the getter-setter), a String Author and a String Content. All the details are displayed properly.

The only issue is this second-time checking - it simply refuses to work properly.
What can be the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OnAppearing gets called again when you close a modal.

This means that next time you hit the ItemSelected, the code will be run twice.

Only on [iOS](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/18781/ios-and-android-different-behaviors-for-onappearing) though.

Comment: Indeed OnAppearing was the problem. Moved the event assignment to the constructor and now it works as it was supposed to.

Answer (score 2):

you can also set a variable to check if the page is loaded for the first time.

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
   if (_isFirstLoad) {
   //-- create your list
   //-- _isFirstLoad = true;
   }
}
```